# perl read the regular expression from a filere

Tags: regex, perl

Howdie

I 've classified all the regular expressions I used the most as library files. To give a dummy example, I have a file called `/mysdk/library/regex/email/match` with the contents:

```
^[a-z]@[a-z]\.com$
```

(I know this is not the good regex, but that's for the example :)). And I have a lot of folders with commonly used regular expressions:

```
/library
  /regex
    /email
    /url
    /social_security
    ...
```

Now I'm doing a Perl script that will tell me if a given string matches a given regular expression from my library. For example,

```
perl my-script.pl email john@example.com
```

And the script should print 0 on false and 1 on true. But it does not work :( This my script:

```
if($ARGV[1])
{
    if(open(REGEX_CONSTANT,"/mysdk/library/regex/$ARGV[0]/match"))

    {
        $regex_constant=<REGEX_CONSTANT>;
        close(REGEX_CONSTANT);

        if($ARGV[1] =~ m/$regex_constant/) { print 1; exit }
    }

    print 0
}

else

{
    print 0
}
```

I've also tried

```
if($ARGV[1] =~ m/($regex_constant)/) { print 1; exit }
```

Even when the string is supposed to match, it prints 0. I know it finds the file and successfully reads the content from it because I've debugged that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you have trailing newlines on those, or maybe headers. Try running chomp on the strings you read in. Hard to tell without know what the files look like.

Comment: Thank you, it was related to a trailing new line!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered looking at `Regexp::Common`

This might not solve your problem directly, but could help you classify and its already includes some very common regex's you may find useful.

Comment: Interesting! For the moment, I'd rather have library files because I code in Bash and PHP (and now Perl and Python) so it's more portable that way. But in my process of learning Perl it sure helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting the regular expressions in files, you might consider putting them in a module:

```
# In FavoriteRegex.pm.
package FavoriteRegex;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT    = qw();
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(%FAVS);

our %FAVS = (
    foo     => qr/foo/,
    integer => qr/\A\d+\Z/,
);

1;
```

Scripts that need those regular expressions become much simpler:

```
# In some_script.pl.
use strict;
use warnings;

use FavoriteRegex qw(%FAVS);

say 'foo'        if 'blah foo blah' =~ $FAVS{foo};
say 'integer'    if '1234'          =~ $FAVS{integer};
say 'integer?!?' if '1234.0'        =~ $FAVS{integer};
```

Even if your project requires that the regular expressions to live in their own non-Perl files, the work of reading those files should be done in the module (`FavoriteRegex.pm` in this example), not the scripts.